# Rotating array members

Tags: javascript, array

I had a situation when I needed to move all array elements in circular fashion. When I say this, I mean:

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 0
2 3 0 1
3 0 1 2
```

The array:

```
var players = ["hash1","hash2","hash3","hash4"];
```

- `Players` is the array that contains user hashes and their place on the table. Table is round, so array must rotate in circular fashion.
- `Step` dictates by how much it should move.

I came up with following algorithm (if you can call that, probably not) that works fine. I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way. Or cleaner way to do same?

The `offset` variable is probably wrongly named; I couldn't come up with a better name.

```
var step = 0 // 3,2,1,0
    var offset = 0;
    var players_new = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= players.length - 1; i++) {
        if (i + step <= players.length - 1) {
            players_new[i + step] = players[i];
            offset++;
        } else {
            players_new[i - offset] = players[i];
        }
    };
```

I tested many different versions, and looks like vazha's version is the fastest all around, except in Firefox.

[jsperf](http://jsperf.com/rotate-array-javascript)

Since I'm using this code in node.js, which uses the Chrome engine, results are important.

Comment: Why not leave the data as-is and use `%`?

Comment: @MattBall Can you illustrate? I'm not following.

Comment: If you haven't already see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/javascript-array-rotate

Comment: Yea it seems like `shift()` is the performance killer and reading the specs, shift is a generic method that reads properties of the array to determine how to shift it. So in a all rounder way shift is easy but your solution only works for your use case. It is impressive performance increase in your case :) I hope your Array contains millions of players :)

Comment: @ppumkin yep, shift is the culprit. thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: I was wondering about that, how many players are you expecting and how often are you planning to call this? Mayhaps rotating the array is not the best thing to do.

Comment: @konijn well, I cannot give you numbers beforehand, but it is major part of the game. This problem was more like a mental challenge to play with minor optimization, that might not be so important down the road, but makes gray matter in the brain work. This is why I enjoy programming. I think programming is not just about finding the solution, but finding smart one and enjoying the process. I might be too drunk atm, but you get the point.

Answer (score 11):

You should use `shift` and `push`

```
function rotate( array , times ){
  while( times-- ){
    var temp = array.shift();
    array.push( temp )
  }
}

//Test
var players = ['Bob','John','Mack','Malachi'];
rotate( players ,2 )
console.log( players );
```

`shift` removes the first element, `push` adds an element at the end.
I am not sure whether you are using players_new because you do not know how to modify the original array or because you do not want to modify the original. If you do not want to modify the original array you could:

```
function rotate( array , times ){
  array = array.slice();
  while( times-- ){
    var temp = array.shift();
    array.push( temp )
  }
  return array;
}

//Test
var players = ['Bob','John','Mack','Malachi'];
console.log( rotate( players ,2 ) );
```

Finally, if you meant to declare an array, you should have `var players_new = [];`, not `var players_new = {};`. Plus `players_new` is an unfortunate name.

Golfic edition:

```
while(times--)array.push(array.shift());
```

Comment: I need to read more about built in capabilities of javascript :)

Comment: what would you call players_new? p.s. I need original array too.

Comment: Probably I would use `seatings` and `newSeatings` ?

Comment: Thanks. Btw, my version is much faster than shift and push you proposed.

Comment: Take a look, maybe I'm doing something wrong. But your proposed solution is 63% slower. http://jsperf.com/rotate-array

Comment: And it gets progressively slower when there are more players in the original array.

Comment: looks like we have a winner http://jsperf.com/rotate-array-javascript

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it is a good idea to abstract this sort of problem. In many languages doing array-based shifts is very expensive.

Do you need to rotate the array? Why not just virtually 'rotate' your pointer....

```
for (int turn = 0; turn < 10; turn++) {

    console.log("First player is " + players[(turn + 0) % players.length]);
    console.log("Last player is " + players[(turn + players.length - 1) % players.length]);

}
```

Alternatively, if you need to create the full array for other reasons, consider the slice and concat:

```
for (turn = 0; turn < 10; turn++) {
    var offset = turn % players.length;
    console.log(offset);
    var playturn = players.slice(offset).concat(players.slice(0, offset));
    console.log(playturn.join(", "));

}
```

Comment: I like your 2nd suggestion is smart, +1

Comment: @konijn Well smart, but 80% slower than my solution.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/rotate-array/3

Comment: @salivan I am surprised it is that much slower, but it **is** my plan-B suggestion. Plan-A is to use the modulo on the index to just 'logically' rotate the array. It requires a different type of support-code outside the function

Comment: looks like we have a winner: http://jsperf.com/rotate-array-javascript